# The concept of nakedness: Is being naked an evil in and out of itself?

Tags: genesis, good-and-evil

The Bible tells us that Adam and Eve, before their fall, were naked and were not ashamed of that (Gen. 2:25). However, right after their fall, that is, after they partook of the tree of knowledge of good and evil, "*they realized they were naked*" (Gen 3:7, NIV).

I take it as a given that Adam and Eve realized even prior to their fall that their bodies were not covered by anything. In other words, when the Scripture says that right after their fall Adam and Eve "*realized they were naked*" it means something other than merely realization of the fact that they were not covered by anything (Adam's answer to God indicates that, too: "*I heard you in the garden, and I was afraid because **I was naked**; so I hid*", Gen. 3:10, NIV - note that Adam heard the voice of God already after having covered himself with a covering that he had made for himself).

Perhaps, what they realized right after the fall was that abiding in a state of not being covered was an evil (after all, they had partaken of the tree of knowledge of only two things: good and evil, and if the state of not being covered were a good, then they would have not needed to cover themselves). But if so, it begs the question of why did God then create them in an evil state in the first place? If being not covered is an evil in and out of itself, why didn't God create some coverings for Adam and Eve right at the moment of their creation? How is this matter explained in traditional Christianity?

✱ By "traditional Christianity" I mean those who identify themselves as Christians and have the practice of addressing Jesus in their prayers.

Comment: I think this would have to be scoped as there is much disagreement as to the nature of the transgression in Eden and as to the exact _state_ of humanity in its first inception. Since skins were granted by God to cover the nakedness, some suggest that another _humanity_ was always a necessity, and, indeed, was promised (in the seed of the woman) and fulfilled in the Incarnation, Resurrection and Acension of a New Head over a New Humanity, Jesus Christ. Up-voted +1.

Comment: Correct.  It is not the physical nakedness that is primarily at issue.  They were naked and not ashamed and THEN they were naked and afraid.

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/40448/nakedness-in-the-bible

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the full answer to your question. But I am going to share with you a few observations.

First, putting on Christ, whose name in Hebrew means salvation, is the picture of being saved. Nakedness is probably a picture of the opposite.

*10 I will greatly rejoice in the LORD, my soul shall be joyful in my God; for he hath clothed me with the garments of salvation, he hath covered me with the robe of righteousness, as a bridegroom decketh himself with ornaments, and as a bride adorneth herself with her jewels.*
Isaiah 61

*14 But put ye on the Lord Jesus Christ, and make not provision for the flesh, to fulfil the lusts thereof.*
Romans 13

*1 For we know that if our earthly house of this tabernacle were dissolved, we have a building of God, an house not made with hands, eternal in the heavens.
2 For in this we groan, earnestly desiring to be clothed upon with our house which is from heaven:
3 If so be that being clothed we shall not be found naked.
4 For we that are in this tabernacle do groan, being burdened: not for that we would be unclothed, but clothed upon, that mortality might be swallowed up of life.
5 Now he that hath wrought us for the selfsame thing is God, who also hath given unto us the earnest of the Spirit.
6 Therefore we are always confident, knowing that, whilst we are at home in the body, we are absent from the Lord:
7 (For we walk by faith, not by sight:)
8 We are confident, I say, and willing rather to be absent from the body, and to be present with the Lord.
9 Wherefore we labour, that, whether present or absent, we may be accepted of him.
10 For we must all appear before the judgment seat of Christ; that every one may receive the things done in his body, according to that he hath done, whether it be good or bad.
11 Knowing therefore the terror of the Lord, we persuade men; but we are made manifest unto God; and I trust also are made manifest in your consciences.
12 For we commend not ourselves again unto you, but give you occasion to glory on our behalf, that ye may have somewhat to answer them which glory in appearance, and not in heart.
13 For whether we be beside ourselves, it is to God: or whether we be sober, it is for your cause.
14 For the love of Christ constraineth us; because we thus judge, that if one died for all, then were all dead:
15And that he died for all, that they which live should not henceforth live unto themselves, but unto him which died for them, and rose again.
16 Wherefore henceforth know we no man after the flesh: yea, though we have known Christ after the flesh, yet now henceforth know we him no more.
17 Therefore if any man be in Christ, he is a new creature: old things are passed away; behold, all things are become new.*
2 Corinthians 5

Also Matthew 22:1-14.

Second, nakedness in Genesis 2 is a different word than in Genesis 3. It is **arom** (H6174) in G2, and **eyrom** (H5903) in G3.

- „**arom** means naked as a state of being, and as such is morally
  neutral, meaning that it doesn’t reflect on whether or not this state
  of being is a good thing or a bad thing; it just is. An example might
  be if a person said that they were naked in the shower this morning;
  their having been naked in the shower is just a fact and neither good
  nor bad.”
- „**eyrom** means nakedness or naked, and is used to indicated nakedness
  with a sense of danger or threat of harm. Aside from the sense of
  danger or of a threat, this too is a simple state of being; morally
  neutral.  An interesting example of this word is found in the Genesis
  3 examples which you will recall are the post-Fall examples of Adam
  and Eve. After they had rebelled against God, their “eyes were
  opened” and they realized they were naked, so they covered themselves
  with leaves sewn together and hid from God. What were they afraid of
  why were they ashamed? Were they afraid of their bodies or were they
  afraid of what God would do? Were they ashamed of their nakedness, or
  were they ashamed of what they had done?"

God did not create them in an evil state. He said that everything He created was good. I think that Adam and Eve being naked show us that God created them with a choice. Would they wait and let God dress them to be fully in His own image, or take from the forbidden tree to make themselves like God/god (elohim)? They did non wait. As a result, they weren't dressed in His light and didn't enter His rest. Instead, being elevated, they were brought a notch down (dressed in animal skins) and exiled.

Comment: Thank you for this input. The more I look into the matter of the state of humanity in its first inception, the more I get exposed to this idea that, even though it was very good (Gen. 1:31), it was not perfect. And it looks like that imperfection was only temporary and, therefore, God didn't want humans to even know anything about it. Thanks also for pointing out the difference between the words for nakedness in Gen. 2 and Gen. 3. I am quite positive that that difference has a lot of meaning and has a direct bearing on the subject matter.

Comment: You may also find interesting that leather/skin (עור) and light (אור) in Hebrew are pronounced exactly the same OR. God's always wanted to clothe men with light (e.g. Matthew 13:43, 1 Corinthians 15, etc.), but He had to cover Adam and Eve with the tunics of skins (Genesis 3:21). For a time. The purpose of creation will be fulfilled in redemption.

Comment: Do we really know how those words were being pronounced at that time? As far as I know, Hebrew text doesn't depict the pronunciation of vowel sounds in words and the vocalization signs were created only in the first century by Massoretes.

Comment: We don't. But play on words in the thing in the Bible. There are so many.

Comment: If the vowel sounds in the two words are different, this may not even fall into a category of play on words.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this Great Question ...

I can answer it in Great Detail (which could take quite a few thousand words), or I can summarize it to 'The Basics' that were 1) Before Sinning and 2) After Sinning

1. Before Sinning: Man (meaning both, male and female) was created in "The Image of God" as 'A Glorious Being' ... (we can have a bit of understanding of what 'A Glorious Being looks like, by observing Scriptures like: Mark 9:2-3, Luke 11:36, and Luke 24:4 (among others), where The Light of The Glory of God Emanates from The Oneness with God in The Spirit. That Glory is 'surrounding' the Glorified Body, to such an extent that even if one may want to 'guess' the 'sexual connotation' of a glorified being, ... it will be Impossible to do so because of the Glorious Light. It is almost impossible for us to Really Understand what Jesus was talking about, when He was praying (in John 17:5), ... "Father, glorify Me together with Yourself, with the glory which I had with You before the world existed" ... (some call this the "Shekinah Glory" ... Who is The Glorious Presence / Visible Manifestation of The Invisible God into His Visible Creation). You can also see a bit of what The Glory of God in Adam was (who was created as God's Temple, according to 1 Corinthians 3:16), by looking at How The Glory of God was Manifested in The Jewish Temple built by Solomon (see 2 Chronicles 7:1-3, "The Glory of God filled The Temple" -NASB-). Simply put, ...when we will be 'clothed' into God's Glory, while having Glorified Bodies, that will be Such AN OVERWHELMING EXPERIENCE that the last thing that one may want to do, is to 'visualize' any sexual identification ...
2. After Sinning (Always Remember SIN as an Acronym -'Self-Inflicted-Nonsense'), Man (both male and female) lost that Glory in which they were 'clothed' immediately after Adam (NOT Eve) eat from the Fruit, which proves that in God's Eye, man's sin was complete only After Both, Male and Female (Genesis 3:7) partook in it. That was NOT God's Will, but Man's Free Will at its worse, acting in Disobedience and Rebellion against God's Word, God's Will and God's Wisdom ... The Price that The Man (both, male and female), Immediately Paid (as God said), was that The Man Died in The Spirit (who was The Venue of Communicating with God every morning (see Genesis 3:8), meaning that it was 'Immediately Unclothed' from God's Glory, which Automatically Precluded Man to attend God's Presence (due to its newly perceived 'nakedness'... which was an unintended consequence of man's sin / disobedience) ...

*** Besides, the Glorified Body (see John 20:14) is most likely made of the same 'spiritual new material' as the clothes that the Glorified body is covered with, since it is subject to 'teleportation' ... (it will be at least 'Ludicrous' to even imagine that Jesus, after being Resurrected, was walking naked in the Jewish marketplace, to buy some clothes for Himself) ...

*** I hope that this will answer your question ...

Comment: "Man (both male and female) lost that Glory in which they were 'clothed' immediately after Adam (NOT Eve) eat from the Fruit" - How do you know that the loss of Glory did not happen to Eve immediately after she ate the fruit (that is, before Adam ate)?

Comment: Because God Created MAN in God's Image (as A Triune One) ... Only after Both, Adam and Eve eat from the fruit ... The Sin was "Conceived" (The Third Aspect of Man's Triunity).

Comment: How does the fact that man was created in God's image prove that Eve didn't lose her glory immediately after eating the forbidden fruit?