# Did God's interaction with Adam and Eve cause their bodies to radiate light hence covering their nakedness?

Tags: genesis, adam, body

Is there any Biblical text that confirms to us if God covered the naked bodies of Adam and Eve with the light that covers his throne prior to their fall. It would have been logical for their bodies to be covered because it is believed that God visited them oftenly in the garden and I don't think the sight of interacting with them while they were naked would have been pleasant to God but since we are all born in the same state Adam and Eve were created in then it leaves room for speculation.

Since they were innocent then the glory of God which is light covered them but then after they sinned, the glory of God left them and then they were exposed.

This idea is rooted in Exodus 34:29 where it is written that Moses interacted with God and he radiated light due to this.

**Exodus 34:29**

> When Moses came down from Mount Sinai, with the two tablets of the testimony in his hand as he came down from the mountain, Moses did not know that the skin of his face shone because he had been talking with God.

Adam and Eve also interacted with God and their bodies must have been covered with the same light?

Comment: If your Q can show some biblical basis for such a supposition, it could be pursued. As it stands, only personal opinion is offered, including an apparent aversion to the naked human body, with the assumption that God would find that offensive when he visited the garden - despite having created the first two humans perfect. And God would also see their nakedness from heaven, before visiting the garden. If the answer to the Q is, "No, there's no biblical text that confirms that speculation", that's not much of an answer. But if you can give us some verses to support the thesis, we can get going.

Comment: You need to [edit] this to give some context for this question. Because otherwise it's totally inexplicable.

Comment: Also, why would God make something in his very good creation that he'd find unpleasant??? Huh?

Comment: @Anne, angels are created clothed. Daniel saw Gabriel clothed while they talked at the River Euphrates, covering nakedness is from God because he gave them clothes made from lamb skins.

Comment: It's fun how this question is almost exactly the opposite of https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/40448/nakedness-in-the-bible

Comment: @kutschkem, the clothing state of Adam and Eve prior to the fall

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel What I mean is, one presupposes that clothedness is or represents something bad, the other that nakedness is or represents something bad.

Comment: @kutschkem,Nakedness is not appropriate that's why God gave them skin clothes made out of a lamb

Comment: @SoFewAgainstSoMany If that were true he would have given them clothes before the Fall.

Comment: @kutschkem, and that's why I asked if the same radiance that covered Moses' face covered their bodies prior to the fall

Comment: @SoFewAgainstSoMany Makes sense now, where you are coming from, but why would then the text say/stress they were naked, and not ashamed, if they were actually clothed in a radiance, that the test does not mention?